# Why does having an array type in a function signature cause doc comment info in hover panels for back-to-back functions to get merged?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've got a C/C++ project generated with MSVC 2019 with some .h files.

Using VSCode 1.73.1 and this configuration of Intellisense :

[image]

Here is the result of Intellisense when I hover on the methods :

[image]

[image]

It seems that characters "`[]`" from the bar and another_bar methods parameters mess up the parsing.

Removing the "`[]`" from the methods parameters did the trick, yet I feel like this is either a bug or a misconfiguration, because I think that `const char[]` is quite common in C/C++ project code.

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure Intellisense to output the correct comment on the yet_another_bar methode, which I believe should only show "`yet_another_bar` brief"?

Perhaps it is wrong to use `const char[]` in header files? Please let me know.

Comment: "Perhaps it is wrong to use `const char[]` in header files?" No, it's not wrong. A little bit *misleading* perhaps, as it's really a pointer but it's not wrong.

Comment: Please provide the repro in textual form inside a code block. Help people reproduce the issue (see [ask]).

Comment: My first thought was "why are you using C-style arrays in the first place rather than `std::array` or `std::vector`?".. Forget that C-style arrays exist in the language - they are more trouble than they are worth and are best forgotten (IMHO).

Comment: As @Someprogrammerdude points out `const char t[]` is simply an alternate way to specify what in reality is `const char *t`. Likely VScode has a quirk seeing the *incomplete type* style pointer parameter.

Comment: Reference: [C++ Standard (latest draft) - 7.3.3 Array-to-pointer conversion \[conv.array\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.array)

Answer (score 0):

I'm on version 1.14.1 of the `vscode-cpptools` extension and I can reproduce this issue with the following:

```cpp
// A
void a(int[]);
// B
void b(int[]);
// C
void c(void);
```

Interestingly, if the middle one is switched to use `/**/`-style comments, then it doesn't happen for either the middle or last one:

```cpp
// D
void d(int[]);
/* E */
void e(int[]);
// F
void f(void);
```

So if you're desperate and willing to change your comment styles, you can use that as a workaround. There's another workaround that it perhaps less drastic: just put at least one empty line between the declarations / definitions:

```cpp
// A
void a(int[]);

// B
void b(int[]);

// C
void c(void);
```

I highly doubt this behaviour with `[]` is intended. This is worth a bug report / issue ticket at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.